# responsive navigation bar with dropdown

Tags: html, css

I want to implement inline right side navigation bar with dropdown. When screen size is small, I am hiding all menus and displaying button. On clicking button I am displaying vertical navigation bar.

In media query I dont know how to hide and show dropdown.
In media query I am able to hide dropdown but I am unable to show it again.

This is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Business 2</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
.nav {
  float: right;
  list-style: none;     
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0;
  display:inline;
}
.nav > li {                          
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 10px 9px 10px 9px;                               
}
.nav > li a {                                               
     text-decoration: none;
     color: black;
     font-size: 16px;
     padding: 20px 15px 20px 15px;
 }

 .nav > li > a:hover {
     color: black;
 }
 
 ul li > ul li {
      position:relative;
      display:none;
      width:150px;
      height:50px;
      line-height:50px;
}
     
.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: black;
  background-color: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav-right a:hover {
  background-color: #E7E7E7;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 80px;
  top: 40px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
.nav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 680px) {

  ul.nav li a {display: none;}
  
  ul > li .dropbtn{
    display: none;
  }
  
  ul.nav li a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 680px) {
  ul.nav.responsive {position: relative;}
  ul.nav.responsive li a.icon{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
 ul.nav.responsive li  {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  ul.nav.responsive li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  
  ul.nav.responsive li.dropdown-content {position: relative;}
  ul.nav.responsive li.dropdown{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="nav" id="topnav">
    <li><a href="#" class="active" >item1</a></li>
    <li>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="dropbtn">item2
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#">subitem1</a>
                <a href="#">subitem2</a>
                <a href="#">subitem3</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">item3</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>           
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("topnav");
  if (x.className === "nav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
  
    x.className = "nav";
  }
  
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this whitin your media query :

```
          ul.nav.responsive li .dropbtn{
            display: block;
          }
```

Comment: it is working but, in media query on displaying menu dropdown content hiding dropdown menu(i.e.item2). how to display dropdown content below dropdown menu.

Comment: You can change this     ul.nav.responsive li.dropdown-content {position: relative;}
for this      .dropdown-content {position: relative;}
within the media query

Comment: for navs it is better to work with visibility:hidden|visible rather than display:block|none sometimes

Comment: @sebdav- ur suggestion helped me, but what is the difference between  ul.nav.responsive li.dropdown-content {position: relative;} and dropdown-content{position: relative;}

Comment: the problem really is a space between "li" and ".dropdown-content". without space what you select is a li element with class "dropdown-content" but if you put a space what you select is an element with class "dropdown-content" child of "li" ...
change this "li.dropdown-content" to "li. dropdown-content"